# What's the difference between "a picture of the king" and "a picture of the king's"?

Tags: possessives, apostrophe, double-possessive

> A picture of the king.
>
> A picture of the king's.

What exactly is the difference between the two?

Comment: You might be interested in our proposed sister site specifically for [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=NIy3I1OlXZ2EgMrV1X1RuQ2). You can support it by committing. Thank you.

Comment: I do not believe this question is appropriate for EL&U as it is very basic.

Comment: I think you will find your answer in [these questions](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/double-genitive).

Comment: Please see [the double-genitive tag wiki](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/double-genitive/info) for details.

Answer (score 2):

The first one is a depiction of the king. The second one is a picture owned by the king that could be of anything.